# UILabel ugly rotation animation with autolayout

Tags: ios, ios7, rotation, uilabel, autolayout

I have a simple UILabel inside an UIView which follows these constraints :

```
H:|[label]|
```

During rotation animation from `Landscape` to `Portrait`, the label is "unhook" from the right resulting on an ugly animation.

The following pictures should describe the situation better than me :

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YieBj.png) - [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FJf0.png) - [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzeul.png)

It seems that the label set his final width at the beginning of his animation.

That also happens from `Portrait` to `Landscape` but this is less disturbing since the final width > start width (no "unhook" effect).

Did someone already find a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: You could just put the label inside another UIView. Then make the labels background clear.

Comment: Yep, that works well. However, any idea why UILabel behaves like that ? Can it be a bug ?

Comment: I don't really know why it behaves like that. I assume it would be something to do with how it handles layout changes, you could probably override UILabel and mess around with its layout methods.